# Looking for a good way in C++ String to find a keyword without neighboring character being a-z

Tags: c++, string

Using C++, suppose I have a file, and I am looking for a keyword, but I don't want its neighboring character to be a `a-z` or `0-9`.

Say I want to look up key word `U` in a file like this:

```
U 1.2;
Under 2.3;
abcdUefg;
```

I hope first line show up, not the second line or the third line. But note the following is okay too.

```
"(U|B|tau)"
```

Because here `U` is a single word.

The point is, I want the key word that I am looking for is a standalone word, not a part of the word. What is the best way to do it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    vector<string> lines;
    ifstream myfile ("FILE");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (myfile.good())
        {
            getline(myfile,line);
            lines.push_back(line);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (lines[i].find("keyName") != string::npos)
        {
            printf("Key found!\n");
        }
    }

    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are these all key:value?

Comment: Note that you can do `std::istream_iterator first(myfile), last(); std::vector<std::string> lines(first, last);` to read the entire file into the vector.

Comment: No. Some are just a line. See my edit. Why ask?

Comment: So you want to find U. But not Under?

Comment: Yes, I want `U`, not `Under`.

Comment: `if((lines[i].find("U") != std::string::npos) && (lines[i+1] == ' '))` assuming they're all delimited by a whitespace.

Comment: @Rapptz, sorry, string position `[i+1]` or `[i-1]` could be `{` or `)` or `|` or any other character, I just dont want it to be a-z or 0-9.

Comment: @Daniel consider putting this in your question.

Comment: @chris `last()` should be `last`, should it not? Just as habit to avoid mvp if ever moved to its own decl. (and +1 I totally concur, btw, a most-awesome and very-often-used method for loading a string container).

Comment: @WhozCraig, I wasn't sure if default-construction for it was the same as value initialization. I use `{}` anyway, so no MVP there ;) Also, I meant to say `std::istream_iterator<std::string> ...`.

Comment: @chris it is. my decls are often `ifstream inf(argv[1]); istream_iterator<string> inf_it(inf), inf_eof; vector<string> strs(inf_it, inf_eof);` , and nice catch on the template parameter. (duh).

Comment: @WhozCraig, Thanks, I'll keep it in mind. And I miss that template argument so often (look, I accidentally created a new face) --> >.

Comment: @chris I was laughing when you noted you did only because I do it all the damn time myself. And every time I think "dammit, did it *again*". Glad I'm not the only one.

Comment: Okay, I see, one is line separated, the other is space separated. Thanks @ WhozCraig and chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the string is ASCII a-z and 0-9 you can do..

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
{
    size_t pos = lines[i].find("keyName");
    size_t len = std::string("keyName").length();
    if (pos != string::npos)
    {
        if(!std::isalnum(lines[i][pos+len+1]))
            printf("Key found!\n");
    }
}
```

In which `isalnum` returns true if it's 0-9 or a-z and is located in `<cctype>`

Comment: .... `lines` in my code is defined as a vector of strings, its not a string. `line[i+1]` is another line.

Comment: @Daniel Ah, still easy fix to really. The point of the answer was to bring your attention to `std::isalnum` anyway.

Comment: Is this okay? `if ( pos != string::npos && !std::isalnum(lines[i][pos+len+1]) && !std::isalnum(lines[i][pos-1]) )`. I am just not sure would `pos-1` cause an error or not ...

Comment: @Daniel Assume a string "Hello World", std::string::find for "Hello" will return pos = 0 because "Hello" is in the beginning of the string. Hope that makes that tidbit clear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read each word from each line and compare it against the key.

```
string word;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
{
    // Read words from the line one by one. They should be space separated.
    istringstream iss(lines[i]);
    while(iss >> word) {
       size_t key_loc = word.find("U");

       if(key_loc == word.size()) {
           // Found "U" followed by space
       }
       // If not the last one in the word. Check what is next to it.
       if(key_loc < word.size() && !std::isalnum(word.at(key_loc+1)) ) {
            // Found it not followed by alphanumeric.
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: They're not delimited by anything common so this probably wouldn't work.